# Operator && cannot be applied to 'boolean', 'int

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I am trying to override the equals method but am faced with a 'Operator && cannot be applied to 'boolean','int'' error, which seems to be caused by the last line. My belief is that `pages == otherEntry.pages` returns an int, but why?

```
        @Override
         public boolean equals (Object that) {
            if (this == that) return true;
            if (!(that instanceof BookEntry)) return false;

            BookEntry otherEntry = (BookEntry) that;

            return title.equals(otherEntry.title) &&
                    Arrays.equals(authors, otherEntry.authors) &&
                    Float.compare(otherEntry.rating, rating) &&
                    ISBN.equals(otherEntry.ISBN) &&
                    pages == otherEntry.pages;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Float.compare(otherEntry.rating, rating)` returns an `int`.

Change it to `Float.compare(otherEntry.rating, rating) == 0` if you want to determine if the two floats are equal according to the ordering defined by `Float.compare()`.

The return statement would become

```
        return title.equals(otherEntry.title) &&
                Arrays.equals(authors, otherEntry.authors) &&
                Float.compare(otherEntry.rating, rating) == 0 &&
                ISBN.equals(otherEntry.ISBN) &&
                pages == otherEntry.pages;
```